# Cron doesn't start any command

Tags: cron

I have a problem with cron on my Ubuntu VPS.
Wanted to plan reboot for every day at 12:30
So I've used command `crontab -e` and added line

```
30 12 * * * reboot
```

And nothing. Yes I am logged as ROOT during editing so I don't know where is a problem.
Tried other commands (`echo`...) Even script, but nothing works

Any idea PLEASE?

**Edit:** yep full path resolved the issue. May I ask how to write command: `vncserver` to work with cron please?

Comment: Use full path to the command: `30 12 * * * /sbin/reboot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` runs with a very minimal environment, as a result common environment variables will differ from what you are used to see in the shell.

likewise `PATH` environment variable differs in `cron`. So if you want to run any binary in `cron` you have two options :

- Use the absolute path to the binary executable :

  ```
  30 12 * * * /sbin/reboot
  ```
- Add `PATH` environment variable with desired values at the top of the `crontab` file e.g. :

  ```
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  ```